# Is there a way to do variadic higher-kinded exception throws in Java?

Tags: java, exception, throw, throws

basically the question is in the title.

I'm looking for ways to set an interface method to throw 1..N `java.lang.Exception` subtypes. So far I'm only able to make it work using generic type parameters in the constructor like `interface IFoo<EX extends Exception> { ... }` and then have a method be like `void bar() throws EX;`, but that requires pre-determining the number of exception types or at least to have them all have a shared superclass and throwing that in the signatures. Is there a way to do a 'variadic' throw clause in Java like `interface IBaz<EX extends Exception ...>` so I can do something like `class Buzz implements IBaz<IOException, IllegalStateException, SecurityException>` and so forth?

Comment: No, and it seems fairly redundant anyway. Just declare it to throw the base Exception. If your callers particularly care about handling IOException and IllegalStateException differently (and most of the time, they won't), then they can still have a more-specific catch clause for the ones they want to handle separately.

Comment: That makes sense. The exceptions are just examples. The interface is in a legacy codebase that's used by 100+ classes throwing all sorts of standard and custom exception types however. Edit: throwing the generic `java.lang.Exception` is what's done currently, forgot to say